# When/How to correctly delete pointers after using them?

Tags: c++, pointers

Just learning about pointers and was working on this problem, and Im confused. As long as I delete the pointers after I use them, then I should be able to use them, this obviously isn't the case, because its not working. I use new, and it allocates memory on the heap, but its getting an address from the stack, is the issue there, some clarification and best practices advice would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// initialize variables
    double hours=0.0,rate=0.0,overtime=0.0,pay = 0.0;
    double *dptr1 = new double;
    double *dptr2 = new double;
    double *dptr3 = new double;
// getting input from user
    cout << "Enter standard hours worked: ";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "Enter rate of pay: ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "Enter overtime hours(enter 0 for no overtime): ";
    cin >> overtime;
    dptr1 = &hours;
    dptr2 = &rate;
    dptr3 = &overtime;


// calculate pay
    pay = hours * rate + (1.5 * rate * overtime);
// print out the results
    cout << setw(4) << "Standard Hours " << setw(8) << "Rate " << setw(12) << "Overtime " << setw(16) << "Pay " << endl;
    cout.setf(ios::floatfield,ios::fixed);
    cout <<setprecision(0)<< setw(8) << *dptr1 <<setprecision(2)<< setw(13)<< *dptr2 <<setprecision(0)<< setw(13)<< *dptr3 << setw(18)<<setprecision(2)<<pay;
    delete dptr1;
    delete dptr2;
    delete dptr3;


}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing with your code? Why are you `new`ing for these pointers in the first place, if you let them point to other variables later?

Comment: I was reading that new'ing the pointers is good practice. well if it delete the pointers it wont print anything, works fine if i take away the deletes at the bottom. just practicing allocating and dellocating.

Comment: Don't new a pointer if you just want them to point to some variable.

Comment: Using `new` in modern C++ is in most cases not what you want to do. And `new` creates a new object that the pointer will point to. If you let it point to something else afterwards, you should have never created a new object. And `delete` only objects created with `new`.

Comment: Gotcha, gotcha, much appreciated mates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А pointer is a variable, meant to point somewhere. It either doesn't point anywhere and must be set to hold `nullptr` value, or holds the address.

The thing is where the address comes from.

It mighgt come from the heap, and that's exactly what `new` does. `new` is a way of saying 'hey, go dynamically allocate the value of a given type from the heap and give me that address' And this is where you should take care to call `delete` later in order to give the previously allocated storage back to the heap.

Alternativly you can ask for address of a variable which is not dynamically allocated, but is automatically created on the stack. The `&` operator does that.

Your code snippet uses pointer variable to:

- allocate storage dynamically on the heap with `new`
- get the address of an existing variable on a stack, and thus the dynamically allocated storage has leaked
- `delete` something, which doesn't come from heap

Comment: So dont even bother with new when planning on just pointing at a variables address.

Comment: @KelvinDavis If the "something" you want the pointer to point at already exists, don't event bother with `new`. Pointing and `new`-allocating are a bit apart. Use cases of pointing without `new`-allocating are ok, but I can't imagine `new`-allocating without pointing to track that allocated storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you use new to allocate a piece of memory, it will always exist until you call delete for this address.  If you lose this address, the memory will not be released until the end of program.This is called memory leak.